# select only third li

Tags: jquery, select, background, html-lists

how do i select only 3rd( or some other no. of my chioce) li element with jquery?
for ex: 
how do i change the background of only third li with jquery. any help please

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> how do i select only 3rd(

Use the [`eq`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) method like this:

```
$('li').eq(2).css('background', 'yellow');
```

Or you can use this variation of `:eq` filter selector:

```
$('li:eq(2)').css('background', 'yellow');
```

The indexing starts from `0`, you need to specify `2` to actually select the third `li`

***If however you want to select every third element, you need to use [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) like this:***

```
$('li:nth-child(3n)')
```

The index for [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) starts from `1` though.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I fooled around a bit with the selector. As it turns out, using `slice` and act and the whole wrappet set is faster than using `nth-child`. http://www.jsfiddle.net/qbDKN/13/

Comment: @jAndy - I'm getting opposite results, with `eq` almost twice as slow. Remember `nth-child` is a css selector, and is implemented natively by some browsers.

Comment: @Kobi: interesting. I tested on Chrome(5) with slightly better results for `slice` (around 300ms).

Comment: @jAndy - I get about 9400 for `eq`, and about 5800 for `slice`. But wait - in your code, eq **is** the `nth-child` code. How confusing of you :) . So you are right, it is faster.

Comment: @Kobi: Oh dear, my bad I forgot to rename the `time event`. But wow, sounds like a **big** difference than for you.

Comment: Also, on the slice code, you don't keep recalling `find` but use the same list, which I suspect skews the results.

Comment: @Kobi: well true, but it's still realistic. You can't do it otherwise with the `nth-child(xn)` selector.

Comment: @jAndi - one last note - I also found `background` to be slower than `background-color`, which makes sense when you think about it. It probably takes more than a loop to profile the differences `:|`.

Answer (score 7):

If you need the third `li` on all lists, use [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
$('li:nth-child(3)')
```

Comment: That will select every third child not only

Comment: @Sarfraz - that'd be `nth-child(3n)`

Comment: I assume I'm being down-voted because Sarfraz edited his answer to include mine, after claiming it isn't correct. Good times.

Comment: hehe man i didn't down vote you for sure +1 from me though :)

Comment: @Sarfraz - I wasn't suggesting that. Doesn't really matter :)